# SQLAlchemy join a "one to many table" and then filter on the joined table with a set of values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an Entries model that has tags, so every entry can have many tags.  Tags are a model with a value of tag which is the tag string.  I am trying to filter my returned entries on sets of tags. For instance, given two tags, a and b, I want to return only the entries that have both tag a and tag b.

Right now I have OR, in the sense that I can return any entries that have either a or b and I have done it this way.

```
entObjs = Entries.query.join(Entries.tags).filter(Tags.tag.in_(tagList)).all()
```

tagList is a list of strings.  How do I implement the AND, so I get only entries that have all the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar using aliased tables and joins,

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

def test(self, tags):       
    q = self.session.query(models.Item).\
             join(models.ItemTag).\
             join(models.Tag.\
             filter(models.Tag.name == tags[0])
    i = 0
    for tag in tags[1:]:
        alias1 = aliased(models.Tag)
        alias2 = aliased(models.ItemTag)
        q = q.join(alias2, models.Item.id == alias2.item_id).\
              filter(alias1.id == alias2.tag_id).\
              filter(alias1.name == tag)
        i += 1

    print(str(q))
```

Comment: @j-j-Hakala, I don't know if I can do this.  My ItemTag is an association table for which I can't access the fields : original_tag_registration = alchemyDB.Table('original_tag_registration',
    alchemyDB.Column('tag_id', alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('tagTable.id')),
    alchemyDB.Column('entry_id', alchemyDB.Integer, alchemyDB.ForeignKey('entries.id'))
    )

Comment: Wow, took some effort, but I found that table.c.tag_id was the way to go. T hanks for the help.